# ObjectOutputStream in try-with-resources

Tags: java, flush, fileoutputstream, objectoutputstream

I am using `ObjectOutputStream` to write the data into a file. Following is the code snippet.

```
try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f))) 
{
    oos.writeObject(allObjects);
}
```

Questions:

1. Do I need to split the object construction of OOS and FOS separately in try-with-resources? I assume that OOS internally also closes the FOS. So the above code line should be fine.
2. Do I need to explicitly call flush?

The problem being I saw once the file was corrupted and while debugging I had the above mentioned queries.

Comment: The implementation of OOS in my JVM (Oracle) flushes the stream and closes it when OOS.close() is called.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java#ObjectOutputStream.close%28%29

Comment: I was about to post the same as @hovanessyan, it's always good to look by yourself.

Comment: Thanks folks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No:
   Closing ObjectOutputStream will automatically close FileOutputStream
2. No:
   The stream will be flushed automatically on close.

Answer (score 2):

I believe developers should rely on the published general contract.

There is no evidence that an `ObjectOutputStream`'s `close()` method calls `flush()`.

OpenJDK's `ObjectOutputStream#close` is just a vendor implementation, I believe.

And it won't hurt if we flush on the try-with-resources.

```java
try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f))) {
    oos.writeObject(allObjects);
    oos.flush(); // What's possibly going wrong with this?
}
```